# Good practice when using logback, TestNG on a continuous integration server

Tags: java, teamcity, testng, logback

We're using logback and TestNG for our project. Logback is set to output to both to a console and to a file, with the TRACE level when we're doing tests (set in `logback-test.xml` file).

Now, there are two issues. First, when running this on a CI server (TeamCity), we get a 700+MB BuildLog file, which is a waste of space (there is a log file already), and overloads the browser. Second, we can't get Assertion Errors to be printed in the log. Because these are caught by TestNG, they only show up in the TeamCity's UI, but not in the file logs.

What should be good approaches here? I'm thinking about logging at the INFO level on the console, if run under TeamCity, and TRACE otherwise. This I could achieve by using a filter, controlled via an environment variable. For the second issue, I still don't have an idea.

tia,
Nikola

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get the `AssertionError`s printed in the file logs, I ended up implementing TestNG's `ITestListener`:

```
public class ListenerLogger implements ITestListener
{
  private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ListenerLogger.class);

  @Override
  public void onTestStart(ITestResult result)
  {
    LOG.info("Starting {}.{} with parameters {}", result.getTestClass().getName(), result.getTestName(), result.getParameters());
  }

  @Override
  public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult iTestResult)
  {
    LOG.info("Test successful");
  }

  // This belongs to ITestListener and will execute only on the event of fail test
  public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result)
  {
    LOG.error("Test failed!", result.getThrowable());
  }
  ...
}
```

And added that into the `pom.xml` of the project I have under CI:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>my.awesome.project</groupId>
  <artifactId>ci-helper</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```